# MS Access SQL - Properly Nesting multiple UPDATE statements

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Using MS Access, how would one nest multiple UPDATE statements into one query?

I keep getting an error when I try to save the query warning me that characters are found after the end of the SQL statement, since I haven't nested. I am unsure of how to nest these properly.

```
UPDATE Table
SET Table.Pipeline_Phase = "HORSE"
WHERE Table.[COL_1] IS NOT NULL 
 AND Table.[COL_2] IS NULL;

UPDATE Table
SET Table.Pipeline_Phase = "MOUSE"
WHERE Table.[COL_1] IS NULL 
 AND Table.[COL_3] IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE Table
SET Table.Pipeline_Phase = "APPLES"
WHERE  Table[COL_4] IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Update has to be a seperate query. You can use a macro to exectue them in sequence.